# Wordpress Filtering Woocommerce Structured Data

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm figuring out a filter but can't be figured :)

Just want to change PrimaryImageOfPage value with an og:image value in CollectionPage for Taxonomies.

It may be that I have to use `woocommerce_structured_data_product` to filter [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-structured-data.html#source-view.15) and look for the image `$markup['image'] = $image;`

I have created some filters, but it isn't `woocommerce_structured_data_product` I guess.

One of them was like that but it... nah.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', function( $markup ) {
    $markup['image'] = ('rank_math/opengraph/{$network}/image');
    return $markup;
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I have been doing this whole day -_-

Comment: Where did you put the above code snippet? Is the filter called?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó I have put it in function.php

Comment: Is it called? What happens if you put a `die()` or similar in it?

Comment: It'd be dying xd - nothing, I created this filter but isn't working properly, this is for products only and not for taxonomies

Comment: Try the `woocommerce_structured_data_context` filter too.

Comment: Tried out that, but it did not matter :'  - thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Gionthelawa, are you using jetpack plugin??

Comment: @Dharmang nope.

Answer (score 0):

If You inspect the code of the class `WC_Structured_Data`, You would see that `woocommerce_structured_data_product` filter is executed inside function `generate_product_data`

WC Complete Source of the class `WC_Structured_Data` : https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b88b868ab8919b7c854173098b7d6d4ab227f9ee/includes/class-wc-structured-data.php

```
$this->set_data( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', $markup, $product ) );
```

And `generate_product_data` function is executed on action `woocommerce_single_product_summary`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'generate_product_data' ), 60 );
```

So, your code would work on product single page only and not archive/list pages, such as the taxonomy page.
The feature you want to achieve is not feasible out of the box in WC, You will need to customize yourself.

Logically, structured data on a single product page is feasible due to the fact there is only one product and product information is available, on the other hand, product list has more than one product (you might need to consider like you want to show details of first product) so it is ambiguous and not feasible out of the box for WC.